# Subdividing ndarray on category array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray like this:

```
[
    [1,1,1],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,3,3],
    [4,4,4]
]
```

And I would like to create an ndarray which contains all 4 inner arrays subdivided by the following category array [1,2,3,2]. I would like to have it look like this:

```
[
    [
        [1,1,1]
    ], 
    [
        [2,2,2],[4,4,4]
    ],
    [
        [3,3,3]
    ]
]
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly in python?

I am asking this question because I have clustered my dataset using sklearns KMeans and now I want an elegant way of handling all of the elements of each category without too much looping.

Comment: if you opt to get a structure out like that, it wouldn't be a normal numpy array, because those have to be consistent in their shape. You would have to end up getting this into a python structure instead, or a numpy array of python list objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to map arrays with their respective categories and collect the output at the end. The advantage of using a dictionary this way is that it is capable of handling categories that appear out of order too.

```
input_list = [
    [1,1,1],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,3,3],
    [4,4,4]
] 

category = [1, 2, 3, 2]

from collections import defaultdict

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)
#Iterate through each array of input list, and append to temp_dict
for i, arr in zip(category, input_list):
    temp_dict[i].append(arr)

result = list(temp_dict.values())
print(result)
#[[[1, 1, 1]], [[2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4]], [[3, 3, 3]]]
```

Optionally, if the order is important too, use a sort on the dictionary keys.

```
result = [x[1] for x in sorted(temp_dict.items())]
print(result)
```